# compiling Verilog code in Quartus

Tags: verilog, hdl, intel-fpga

I'm new to verilog HDL and my first project is to implement a simple stopwatch counter using a  set of registers. I'm using Altera Quartus.

When I tried compiling the code below, I keep getting an error for each and everyone of the registers. one of the error messages looks like this:

Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "sec0[3]" at test_interface.v(127)

Anyone can help? The code simulates fine in Modelsim.

Here's the fragment of code that's causing problems:

```
always @ (posedge clk)

  if (qsoutput == 1)
      sec0 = sec0 + 1;
  else if (sec0 == 4'b1010) begin
      sec1 = sec1 + 1;
      sec0 = 4'b0000;
  end else if (sec1 == 4'b0110) begin
      min0 = min0 + 1;
      sec1 = 4'b0000;
  end else if (min0 == 4'b1010) begin
      min1 = min1 + 1;
      min0 = 4'b0000;     
  end else if (min1 == 4'b0110) begin
      sec0 = 4'b0000;
      sec1 = 4'b0000;
      min0 = 4'b0000;
      min1 = 4'b0000;
  end
```

Comment: I don't really see anything wrong with just that segment of code. Could you post the entirety of 'test_interface.v', while making a note about which is line 127? Can you also post the entire list of compile errors?

Comment: Actually i'm getting multiple errors for each line of code, not just 127. it goes on like this: Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "sec0[3]" at test_interface.v -- Error (10028): Can't resolve multiple constant drivers for net "sec1[3]" at test_interface.v etc etc

Comment: Understood, but we need more information from you. Please post the two things that I requested if you want me to look further. You may select `edit` to add them to the bottom of your post.

Comment: here's a link to the code: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6bhu6bvcbkgnnp/mycode.txt) I'm sorry it's my first time using this website and I'm having problems to format the code here itself!

Comment: Not a problem, welcome. If you want to paste code in, just copy a large block, paste it into the editor, select the entire block of text that represents your code, and press Ctrl-K or click on the curly braces in the editor bar. That should format it nicely as a code sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [your code in Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6bhu6bvcbkgnnp/mycode.txt), you are assigning registers in multiple `always` blocks. This is illegal for synthesis and cosponsors to the Altera Quartus error message is referring to. A `reg` type should only be assigned with in one `always` block.

As an example, `sec0` is defined in `always @(posedge reset_reg)` and the code provided in your question. The [code in Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h6bhu6bvcbkgnnp/mycode.txt) is even worse because you split the counter logic into 4 separate always blocks that assign `sec0`.

I suggest you put all `sec*` and `min*` resisters one clock synchronous always block with an asynchronous:

```
always(@posedge clk or posedge reset_reg)
begin
  if(reset_reg)
  begin
    // ... asynchronous reset code ...
  end
  else
  begin
    // ... synchronous counter code ...
  end
end
```

This paper goes into detail about good verilog coding practices for synthesis: 
http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf

---

Other issues you will have:

- Use non-blocking (`<=`) when assigning registers. This is discussed in [Cliff's paper](http://www.sunburst-design.com/papers/CummingsSNUG2000SJ_NBA.pdf) mentioned earlier.
- Get rid of the initial block. I understand some FPGA synthesizers allow it and some ignore it. It is a better practice to have an asynchronous to put everything into a known and predictable value.
- The block starting with `always @ (clk or start_reg or lap_reg or reset_reg)` has a bizarre sensitivity list and will likely give you problems. you wither want `@(*)` if you want combination logic or `@(posedge clk or posedge reset_reg)` for synchronous flops.
- Very rarely dual edge flops are used. The line `always @ (posedge clk or negedge clk)` should be `always @ (posedge clk)` for synchronous or `always @(*)` for combination logic.